# Prepopulate form in an iFrame using string data

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a scenario where one form leads to another and the second one is inside an iFrame. I wanted to figure out how to pass string data onto the form within the iFrame. I've tried a few JavaScript codes I found online but none are working

Comment: post your code so we can help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot view/modify within an iframe. Even if you set CORS most browsers block a lot of functionality today. 
if you have control of both sites you can use post messages.

Answer (score 0):

if your iframe's id is 'if', this will give you the inner doc

```
var innerDoc = document.getElementById("if").contentDocument;
```

then you can find your element from there.